# Filtering Tab's in Tab Bar Controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, xcode9

### Tab Bar Controller Filter

I have a Tab bar Controller view and im looking to filter a view depending on login credentials.

[Here is the Tab Bar Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAkuz.png)

Im Looking to, for example if the user is a normal user, Remove the "Paperwork" Tab. Or even replace the "Paperwork" with another tab.

Any help is much appreciated!! Thanks

Comment: Why filter them at all? Just set the view controllers correctly first time round. The docs show a function `setViewControllers`.

Comment: thanks Fogmeister ill attempt it and see where i get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can the viewControllers property to get all the view controllers associated with the TabController as an array. Depending on your filter condition delete the corresponding viewController from the array.
Ex: you can remove paperwork from the tabs using

```
tabBarController?.viewControllers?.remove(at: 1) --> 1 because paperwork is at index 1.
```